# RxSwift Observable does not emit value

Tags: ios, swift, observable, rx-swift

I have this Observable :

```
func getCategories() -> Observable<[LKCategory]>{
    return Observable<[LKCategory]>.create { observer -> Disposable in
        self.storeHandler.fetchRegions(forStoreID: self.storeID) { (regions, error) in
            if let uwError = error {
                observer.on(.error(uwError))
            }else {
                observer.on(.next(regions?.map{ self.regionToCategory(region: $0) } ?? [LKCategory]()))
                observer.on(.completed)
            }
        }
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

and I subscribe like this :

```
    self.getCategories()
        .subscribe(onNext: { (cat) in
            print("print")
        }, onError: { (error) in
            print("print")
        }, onCompleted: {
            print("print")
        }, onDisposed: {
            print("print")
        }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

I pass into my observable, especially in `.next` and `.completed` lines

But in my subscribe, i have no prints...

Comment: "i have no prints..." Of course you can't see any, because you are printing out empty strings...

Comment: i have update my code, in order to print "print", but with no success

Answer (score 0):

The only reason for this observable not triggering any of the blocks passed in subscribe is that your `fetchRegions` function does not actually call the completion block.